# Problems drawing a flowchart with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

right now I'm trying to create a flowchart in LaTeX. I'm using the Tikz package and so far I have this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=5em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
  \node [block] (sam) {Sample};
  \node [block, right of=sam] (var) {Variable Selection};
  \node [block, right of=var] (pro) {Data Colection/ Cleaning};
  \node [block, right of=pro] (clu) {Clustering Algorithm Selection};
  \node [block, below of=clu] (clus) {Clustering};
  \node [block, left of=clus] (val) {Cluster Validation};
  \node [block, left of=val] (res) {Result Interpretation};
  \node [block, left of=res] (kno) {Knowledge};

  \draw [->] (sam) -- (var);
  \draw [->] (var) -- (pro);
  \draw [->] (pro) -- (clu);
  \draw [->] (clu) -- (clus);
  \draw [->] (clus) -- (val);
  \draw [->] (val) -- (res); 
  \draw [->] (res) -- (kno);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using this code I obtain this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCPbo.jpg

However, I need some arrows going in the opposite direction in between some of the blocks, namely: clu, clus, var and res. What I'm aiming is to create an adaptation of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKD57.jpg

Additionally, I would like to ask if this package allows for one of the nodes to be an image. I still haven't tried anything concerning this part, but I would like to use some of the elements of the last flow chart... Particularly the ones above data samples, knowledge and clusters. If you could indicate me where to begin I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an alternative, less elementary solution. employed are `tikz` libraries `arrows.meta`, `chains` and `positioning`. in nodes positioning is used syntax from the library `positioning`; displacement of arrows is done with `transform canvas`; styles definitions is moved to `tikzpicture` options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 15mm and 10mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white,
                 text width=6em, minimum height=5em,
                 align=center},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={block, on chain}]
\node (sam) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
\node (var) {Variable Selection};
\node (pro) {Data Colection/ Cleaning};
\node (clu) {Clustering Algorithm Selection};
\node (kno) [below=of sam]  {Knowledge};
\node (res) {Result Interpretation};
\node (val) {Cluster Validation};
\node (clus) {Clustering};
    \end{scope}
\draw [->]
    (sam) edge (var)
    (var) edge (pro)
    (pro) edge (clu)
    (res)  --  (kno);
\draw [->,transform canvas={xshift=-1ex}]
    (clu) -- (clus);
\draw [->,transform canvas={xshift= 1ex}]
    (clus)  -- (clu);
\draw [->,transform canvas={yshift=1ex}]
    (clus) edge (val)
    (val)   to  (res);
\draw [->,transform canvas={yshift=-1ex}]
    (res) edge (val)
    (val)  to (clus);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is rather straightforward to draw these arrows and no, you do not have to load an additional package. Ti*k*Z automatically loads the `graphicx` package, and for illustration purposes I replaced the content of your first node by some graphics.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=5em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
  \node [block] (sam) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node [block, right of=sam] (var) {Variable Selection};
  \node [block, right of=var] (pro) {Data Colection/ Cleaning};
  \node [block, right of=pro] (clu) {Clustering Algorithm Selection};
  \node [block, below of=clu] (clus) {Clustering};
  \node [block, left of=clus] (val) {Cluster Validation};
  \node [block, left of=val] (res) {Result Interpretation};
  \node [block, left of=res] (kno) {Knowledge};

  \draw [->] (sam) -- (var);
  \draw [->] (var) -- (pro);
  \draw [->] (pro) -- (clu);
  \draw [->] (clu.-110) -- (clus.110);
  \draw [->] (clus.70) -- (clu.-70);
  \draw [->] (clus.170) -- (val.10);
  \draw [->] (val.-10) -- (clus.190);
  \draw [->] (val.170) -- (res.10); 
  \draw [->] (res.-10) -- (val.190); 
  \draw [->] (res) -- (kno);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that if you want the arrow distance to be universal, you could work with `xshift` and `yshift`, but I personally like the current output a bit better, yet I'll be happy to change that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. From here I can adapt the code and do exactly what I need :)

Comment: @Asheliiin Glad to hear! BTW, if the solution worked for you, you may consider [accepting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) it.